# No se accede a la posición correcta del array en un bucle

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una función que tome el valor de `x`, donde `x` es la posición. Por ejemplo:

- 1 = oro
- 2 = plata
- 3 = bronce

Y que en las demás posiciones sea 0 ó cualquier número posterior a 3 diga "nada". Éste es el código que tengo:

```js
var array = ["oro", "plata", "bronce"]

function medallaSegunPuesto(x) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i == (x - 1)) {
      return array[i];
    } else {
      return "nada";
    }
  }
}

console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(3));
```

El problema es que al poner el `else` no me reconoce la posición 2 ni 3. ¿Sugerencias?

Comment: No me queda claro lo que esperas obtener ... ¿ Podrías poner un ejemplo de valor de entrada -> resultado esperado ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No necesitas un bucle.  Simplemente chequea que el valor se encuentre en el rango indicado, sino retornas "nada".  Algo asi:

```js
var array = ["oro","plata", "bronce"]

function medallaSegunPuesto(x){  
    if(x>0 && x<=array.length){
      return array[x-1];
    }else {return "nada";}  
}
console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(3));
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha servido de maravilla

Comment: Y en caso de querer saber si contiene un premio, ¿Cómo sería? 
Es decir, si tuviera quesaber si la posición 5 tuviera un premio

Comment: Creo que seria la misma funcion.  Si la funcion retorna "nada" es porque no hay premio.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que es mas simple aún usando el o lógico `||`.

```js
var array = ["oro","plata", "bronce"]

const medallaSegunPuesto = (x)=>(array[x-1] || "nada");

console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(3));
console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(43));
console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(-1));
```

Comment: llegaste tarde pero si es mas optimo.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque tienes ya soluciones correctas (y mejores que usar un bucle). Voy a poner la raíz del problema (aunque me imagino que ya la sabes) y una posible solución (aunque sería más sencillo y eficiente optar por otra de las respuestas).

El problema está en el `if...else`, que devuelve valores tanto en el `if` como en el `else`. Eso quiere decir que si el valor es 1 se va a devolver "oro", pero para cualquier otro valor, se va a entrar en el `else` y devolver "nada" sin siquiera comprobar el resto de los índices.

Para solucionar esto podrías quitar el `else` y mover el `return "nada"` justo después del bucle `for`:

```js
var array = ["oro", "plata", "bronce"]

function medallaSegunPuesto(x) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i == (x - 1)) {
      return array[i];
    }
  }
  return "nada";
}

console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(3));
```

De nuevo, esta solución no es la mejor ni la manera rápida de resolver el problema. Pero podría ser útil si en lugar de iterar un array estuvieras iterando sobre los índices de un objeto (aunque seguramente también hay soluciones mejores en ese caso).

Comment: A pesar de que no es la solución ideal, está es una aclaración muy importante, que ninguno hicimos.